# SSL Handshake Client_Hello version

Tags: ssl, version, handshake

I have a very basic question: how does client_hello or server_hello in SSL handshake determine what SSL/TLS version can it support? I mean, as far as I understand, first client and then server send out the highest possible SSL version they support. But, how is this determined?

Is it the version field in a certificate?

Best regards,
HL

Answer (score 2):

This is all described in the [TLS specification, appendix E](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-E.1). This is phrased slightly differently in the TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 specification, but the principle remains the same.

Essentially, the client asks for the highest version it can support and the server responds with the highest version it can support up to the client's version:

```
min(max. client supported version, max. server supported version)
```

This works as long as there the resulting version is indeed supported by both parties.

Comment: I understand this part (of negotiation). But what I do not understand is, how does client know what version itself can handle? To be more precise, how does it know what version to put into client_hello?

Comment: Ah, well it's up to its own TLS library (and perhaps which of the versions supported by that library are enabled via its configuration). An SSL/TLS library where TLS 1.1 is implemented but TLS 1.2 isn't will simply send at most a TLS 1.1 client hello.

Answer (score 0):

The client is responsible for initiating an SSL handshake by sending the ClientHello message. If this isn't the first message that is sent, the server responds with an error and shuts down the socket.

The client advertises to the server which cipher specs it supports, it's not required to support all of them.

The client sends the server the client's SSL version number, cipher settings, session-specific data, and other information that the server needs to communicate with the client using SSL.

The client also sends a challenge token, which the server must encrypt using the newly negotiated key before sending back the encrypted value, in its hello message. The client verifies that the decrypted token is the same as what was sent. If it's not, the handshake is rejected.

View the complete demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qps5dsNSIbc)

Comment: The 'challenge token' is SSLv2. You are twenty years out of date.